# try to make a simple rounded_rectangle with cairo and gtk+-3.6.1 on windows but something goes wrong

Tags: gtk, cairo

I try to make a simple rounded_rectangle with cairo and gtk+-3.6.1 on windows but something goes wrong. think that somithings goes wrong with this version of gtk+-3.6.1 on windows taken from http://www.tarnyko.net/en/. Here are some errors from my code::blocks IDE

main.c (file);

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include "roundedrectangle.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
   GtkWidget *win = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
   //cairo_surface_t *surface = cairo_image_surface_create(CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, 100, 100);
   //cairo_t *cr = cairo_create(surface);
   GtkWidget *image = gtk_image_new_from_file("C:/Users/Doudieu/Desktop/image.png");
   gtk_widget_set_app_paintable(image, TRUE);
   gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(win), image);
   struct user_data data = {50,50,100,100,20};
   user_t *dat;
   dat = &data;
   //g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(win), "expose-event", G_CALLBACK(drawing), (gpointer)dat);
   g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(image), "expose-event", G_CALLBACK(drawing), (gpointer)dat);
   gtk_widget_show_all(win);
   gtk_main();
   return 0;
}
```

roundedrectangle.c (file):

```
#include "roundedrectangle.h"

 int rounded_rectangle(cairo_t *cr, double x, double y, double width, double height, double radius[4])
   {
       if(((width<2*radius[0])&&(width<2*radius[1])&&(width<2*radius[2])&&(width<2*radius[3]))||((width<2*radius[0])&&(width<2*radius[1])&&(width<2*radius[2])&&(width<2*radius[3])))
       {
           printf("values of radius not good\n");
           return -1;
       }
      double from_degre = PI/180;

      //Corner C
      cairo_arc(cr, x+width-radius[2], y+height-radius[2], radius[2], 0*from_degre, 90*from_degre);

      //Corner D
      cairo_arc(cr, x+radius[3], y+height-radius[3], radius[3], 90*from_degre, 180*from_degre);

      //Corner A
      cairo_arc(cr, x+radius[0], y+radius[0], radius[0], 180*from_degre, 270*from_degre);

      //Corner B
      cairo_arc(cr, x+width-radius[1], y+radius[1], radius[1], 270*from_degre, 360*from_degre);

      cairo_close_path(cr);
      return 0;
   }


int rounded_rectangle_uni(cairo_t *cr, double x, double y, double width, double height, double radius)
{
  double radius_uni[4] = {radius, radius, radius, radius};
  if( rounded_rectangle( cr, x, y, width, height, radius_uni ) == -1)
    {
           printf("values of radius not good\n");
           return -1;
    }
  return 0;
}

gboolean drawing(GtkWidget *win, cairo_t *cr, gpointer data)
{
   GtkAllocation allo;
   if(gtk_widget_get_app_paintable(win) == FALSE)
    {
        printf("background will be erase after\n");
        return FALSE;
    }
   cairo_t *c = gdk_cairo_create(GDK_DRAWABLE(win->window));
   gtk_widget_get_allocation(win, &allo);
   struct user_data dat = *((user_t *)data);
   cairo_set_source_rgba(c, 0.2, 0.1, 0, 1);
   cairo_set_line_width(c, 4);
   rounded_rectangle_uni(c, allo.x, allo.y, dat.width, dat.height, dat.border_radius);
   cairo_stroke(c);
   cairo_set_source_rgba(c, 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5);
   rounded_rectangle_uni(c, allo.x, allo.y, dat.width, dat.height, dat.border_radius);
   cairo_fill(c);
   cairo_destroy(c);
   return TRUE;
}

gboolean drawing1(GtkWidget *win, cairo_t *cr, gpointer data)
{
    return TRUE;
}
```

roundedrectangle.h (file):

```
#ifndef ROUNDED_RECTANGLE_H_INCLUDED
#define ROUNDED_RECTANGLE_H_INCLUDED



#endif // ROUNDED_RECTANGLE_H_INCLUDED
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <math.h>
#define PI  3.141592653589793238462643383
typedef struct user_data user_t;

int rounded_rectangle(cairo_t *cr, double x, double y, double width, double height, double radius[4]);
int rounded_rectangle_uni(cairo_t *cr, double x, double y, double width, double height, double radius);

struct user_data
   {
      double x;
      double y;
      double width;
      double height;
      int border_radius;
   };

gboolean drawing(GtkWidget *win, cairo_t *cr, gpointer data);
gboolean drawing1(GtkWidget *win, cairo_t *cr, gpointer data);
```

errors from codeblocks output:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in cairo (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-gcc.exe -mms-bitfields -Wall  -g  -mms-bitfields -Ic:/gtk+/include/atk-1.0 -Ic:/gtk+/include/cairo -Ic:/gtk+/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -Ic:/gtk+/include/glib-2.0 -Ic:/gtk+/lib/glib-2.0/include -Ic:/gtk+/include/pango-1.0 -Ic:/gtk+/include -Ic:/gtk+/include/freetype2 -Ic:/gtk+/include/libpng14 -IC:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/gtk-3.0   -IC:\gtk+\include -IC:\gtk+\include\gtk-2.0 -IC:\gtk+\include\cairo -IC:\gtk+\include\gdk -IC:\gtk+\include\glib-2.0 -IC:\gtk+\lib\glib-2.0\include -IC:\gtk+\include\pango-1.0 -IC:\gtk+\lib\gtk-2.0\include -IC:\gtk+\include\atk-1.0 -IC:\gtk+\include\gdk-pixbuf-2.0  -c C:\Users\Doudieu\Desktop\cairo\main.c -o obj\Debug\main.o
In file included from C:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdk.h:31:0,
                 from C:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:30,
                 from C:\Users\Doudieu\Desktop\cairo\main.c:2:
C:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdkversionmacros.h:147:6: error: missing binary operator before token "("
C:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdkversionmacros.h:155:5: error: missing binary operator before token "("
C:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdkversionmacros.h:158:5: error: missing binary operator before token "("
C:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdkversionmacros.h:164:5: error: missing binary operator before token "("
C:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdkversionmacros.h:172:5: error: missing binary operator before token "("
C:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdkversionmacros.h:178:5: error: missing binary operator before token "("
C:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdkversionmacros.h:186:5: error: missing binary operator before token "("
C:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdkversionmacros.h:192:5: error: missing binary operator before token "("
C:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdkversionmacros.h:200:5: error: missing binary operator before token "("
C:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdkversionmacros.h:206:5: error: missing binary operator before token "("
C:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdkversionmacros.h:214:5: error: missing binary operator before token "("
In file included from C:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkwindow.h:33:0,
                 from C:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkdialog.h:33,
                 from C:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkaboutdialog.h:30,
                 from C:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:31,
                 from C:\Users\Doudieu\Desktop\cairo\main.c:2:
C:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkapplication.h:77:1: error: unknown type name 'GMenuModel'
C:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkapplication.h:80:49: error: unknown type name 'GMenuModel'
C:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkapplication.h:83:1: error: unknown type name 'GMenuModel'
C:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkapplication.h:86:49: error: unknown type name 'GMenuModel'
In file included from C:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkmenu.h:34:0,
                 from C:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtklabel.h:35,
                 from C:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkaccellabel.h:36,
                 from C:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:33,
                 from C:\Users\Doudieu\Desktop\cairo\main.c:2:
C:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkmenushell.h:117:41: error: unknown type name 'GMenuModel'
In file included from C:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtklabel.h:35:0,
                 from C:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkaccellabel.h:36,
                 from C:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:33,
                 from C:\Users\Doudieu\Desktop\cairo\main.c:2:
C:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkmenu.h:119:44: error: unknown type name 'GMenuModel'
In file included from C:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:58:0,
                 from C:\Users\Doudieu\Desktop\cairo\main.c:2:
C:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkbutton.h:84:1: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'void'
C:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkbutton.h:86:1: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'void'
C:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkbutton.h:88:1: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'void'
C:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkbutton.h:90:1: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'void'
In file included from C:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:131:0,
                 from C:\Users\Doudieu\Desktop\cairo\main.c:2:
C:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkmenubar.h:73:42: error: unknown type name 'GMenuModel'
In file included from C:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:132:0,
                 from C:\Users\Doudieu\Desktop\cairo\main.c:2:
C:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkmenubutton.h:82:46: error: unknown type name 'GMenuModel'
C:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkmenubutton.h:84:1: error: unknown type name 'GMenuModel'
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 2 seconds)
24 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 2 seconds)
```

Comment: Please say what exactly goes wrong, provide your `drawing()` callback, and edit the errors into something readable!

Comment: it compiles fine with GTK+2.24 but not with GTK+3.6.1 .   I have a question: is it possible to use border-radius style with GTK+2.24?

Comment: I think you may be using a version of GLib that is too old for GTK 3.6.

Comment: Finally I think that GTK+ is not good for windows (2.24 is a very old version) now. wxWidget :-(  seems to be a good option. One question: is there some styles in 2.24 like border-radius?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below some observations which might be helpful.

1. *Build environment*:
   It appears there is a slight misconfiguration in the build environment from what you have posted. The compiler command has inclusion of directories `c:/gtk+/include/...` whereas the errors all point to `C:/GTK+-3.6.1/include/...`. This could possible be some misconfiguration in project build settings.
   A better way to build would be to make use of `pkg-config`. If you check `bin` folder under the installation path of the package you will see `pkg-config.exe`.
   One way to use this would be by adding settings in your IDE, under "Build Options" of your project, set the "Other options" of "Compiler settings" to **`[GTK_3_6_INSTALLED_DIR]\bin\pkg-config.exe --cflags gtk+-3.0`** (Please note back ticks at the start and end of the command).
   Similarly under "Other options" of "Linker settings" add **`[GTK_3_6_INSTALLED_DIR]\bin\pkg-config.exe --libs gtk+-3.0`**. With these setting you should be able to compile and link your code.
2. *Code*:
   The code which you are using will not compile with Gtk+3.0 due to the changes.
   Please see [this link](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.3/ch25s02.html) for full list of changes. The changes related to your code are as follows:

   - In Gtk+ 3.0, `expose-event` is not available. Make use of [`draw`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-draw) instead in `main.c`.
   - `GdkDrawable` is deprecated in Gtk+ 3.0. Also you cannot access members of `GtkWidget` directly, you will have to make use of accessor functions. Thus in `drawing` function in `roundedrectangle.c`, `cairo_t *c = gdk_cairo_create(GDK_DRAWABLE(win->window));` should be changed to `cairo_t *c = gdk_cairo_create(gtk_widget_get_window(win));`
   - Unless its a typo `#endif // ROUNDED_RECTANGLE_H_INCLUDED` should be at the end of the header file.
   - Whenever you want to *draw* your custom widget, the widget of choice is [`GtkDrawingArea`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkDrawingArea.html) rather than `GtkImage`. It is also possible to set main window as app paintable and draw rounded rectangle on.

Hope this helps!